# Why would assigning a double value to double? cause a NaN

Tags: c#, casting, nan

Here is the scenario! (simplified)

```
double val1 = 0.0;
double? val2 = val1;
```

Why would val2 result in NaN?

Comment: I think the problem has been lost during the "simplified" work. You need to add enough of the original code to reproduce the scenario.

Comment: Maybe my question was too simplified. Under which circumstances would this happen if ever. Logically it should never! But it does???? The actual code does exactly what is listed about, except the values are part of 2 classes passing parameter values.

Comment: My guess it is a 0/0 problem. N/0 would give `Infinity`(n!=0)

Comment: You need to present a *small* but *complete* code sample that *actually* demonstrates the issue. We're quite capable of writing two assignment statements ourselves, and as @Marc points out, the result isn't the result you're describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply: it wouldn't and it doesn't.

The result of assigning a non-NaN `double` to a `double?` is a `double?` with a non-NaN value; in this case `0.0`

Comment: Yes i agree... but my scenario, although a tad bit more complex than the example, basically comes down to exactly that. Thank anyway for the quick answer!!

Comment: @JandeJager no, something is lost in the "basically". You need to post something that *actually does* reproduce what you are seeing. The difference between your original code, and the code you've posted, is where the issue lies.

Comment: I'll try and replicate this without having to post 20000 lines of code... which is probably were the problem lies. Just wanted to find out if there are any obvious reasons for this scenario to occur. But you'll get the 'tick' for being brave to answer a stupid question! Tx!

Comment: @Jan look for divisions. Division of zero by zero is the easiest way to get NaN

Comment: Thank everyone. Yes the problem war a 'divide by zero'!